# Multiple errors while import python module - ModuleNotFoundError and ImportError

Tags: python, python-import

I receive multiple import errors. My directory looks like that:

```
scraping
└── tool_scrapy
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── middlewares
    ├── * other scrapy files *
    └── spiders
       ├── my_spider.py
       └── run_my_spider.py
```

run_my_spider.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from tool_scrapy.spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(CARSPLotomotoSpider)
process.start()
```

I receive many error no matter how I am trying to write my fourth line:

```
from tool_scrapy.spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
```

I am getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tool_scrapy'
```

Or when I add "." before I am getting:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have already tried this things:

```
from tool_scrapy.spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
from .tool_scrapy.spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
from spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
from .spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
from scraping.tool_scrapy.spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
from .scraping.tool_scrapy.spiders.my_spider import my_spiderSpider
```

I have tried adding **main**.py, I have tried adding **init**.py in various places, still nothing.

Also, pycharm is proposing me this first solution (and after adding "." pycharm is correctly proposing me next modules. Yet still, when I try to run it I receive this errors.

What can I try next to resolve this?

### Edit

my_spider.py:

```
from tool_scrapy.items import SpiderItem
```

Here I also tried many similar options, always hitting the same errors.

Comment: Why not just use `from my_spider import my_spiderSpider`?

Comment: Oh, it works. I am as happy as I am confused. Why this works and my version is not working?

And I edited my main post with import in my "my_spider.py". Tutorial are telling me that simple "..items" should work but I am hitting the same errors. Could you also tell me a solution to this one?

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me:

```
import inspect
import os
import sys

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)
```

If anyone could explain me why, I would be very happy.